# By default android scales my png images in the assets folder?

Tags: android, libgdx, android-screen-support

I am developing a game in libgdx. I was searching on the Internet and I just didn't find anything.

Does android by default scale my png images in the assets folder so that they render at the appropriate physical size on each device? And if not, how can I do that? Just put them in mdpi/hdpi folders?

For example:

My stage which renderred the Life bar and all the UI things: (And it just not resizing itself, in my phone it all OK but in for exmaple nexus 5 all is small):

This is my resize method: it don't work at all.

```
    @Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;




    camera.viewportHeight = height / 1.4f;
    camera.viewportWidth = width / 1.5f;

    stage.setViewport(width, height, true);
    //  stage.getCamera().position.set(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,           Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2, 0);

      //All the Tables
        table.invalidateHierarchy();
        table.setSize(width, height);
        table2.invalidateHierarchy();
        table2.setSize(width, height);
        table3.invalidateHierarchy();
        table3.setSize(width, height);



            table4.invalidateHierarchy();
            table4.setSize(width, height);


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything that is in **assets** folder is ignored by compiler, images are not rescaled or any other special logic is applied. That is the case if you are developing with LibGDX or a standart android application. You access assets folder like any other folder.

If you have problem with supporting different screen sizes, check out this [LibGDX tutorial](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-setup,-running-&-debugging). Take a look how the banner texture is rendered across different screen sizes.

Comment: And i do i not ignore them and for each resulotion  I replace the images i want to use?

Comment: I don't think you have to wory about it and just feed these images to SpriteBatch or OpenGL-ES itself and let them handle about rescaling.

Comment: First, thank you very much for your replay, and sorry for my poor english. But  I chcked my application on my device  (Motorola Razr XT-910) and all was OK, but when i checked my app in Nexus 5 phone all goes down and was very small. So there is a way to resizing my images according to the screen resolotion?

Comment: Could you update your question with an example of how are you handling rendering logic ?

Comment: I update, I hope that this is what you are expecting to see, if you want something else just say.